# Dash to Panel not showing running indicator for Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, indicator, 21.10, dash-to-dock

I use the extension Dash to Panel to combine the top bar and the dock, because I have a small 768p screen and both things takes a lot of space.

Since I upgraded to 21.10 the bottom bar doesn't show the running indicator for this particular app (Nautilus), even when I click on the icon when already there's an open session it opens a new one, so it doesn't even seem to recognize that the app is running.

I have to say that this problem doesn't occur with any other apps, I even installed Dolphin and it works fine, also tried updating the extension, and reinstalling the app (this one works but only until I reboot the computer). Already tried differents shells and nothing fixed, any suggestions?

Comment: You start with "So that's the deal" - which I find confusing.  What are you talking about?   Depending on the browser/setup used by users, the title may not be seen when they read your question text, but it's very unclear what you're talking about with that..  The question will get better responses if it's clear (all details need to be in the question!) and if you're talking about https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ for example; that detail (rather than just name) should be provided.  I also suggest voiding expressions of *frustration* as you'll do better with just facts

Comment: It appears this is a known defect with dash to panel, filed here:

https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1497

Answer (score 5):

I spent a few months with this problem, and finally found a solution. Set:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-locations false
```

and log out of/log back in to your gnome session. After this, nautilus will work correctly in the taskbar.

Found the solution here:

https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1500#issuecomment-975520406

Comment: Thanks this solution worked!!